# Linq & Paging - Unable to return paged data with an OrderBy

Tags: .net, wcf, linq-to-sql, paging

I've been trying to implement a simple paging system on a WCF service I've written that uses Linq To SQL To query a database but seem to be going from one problem to another.

I want the WCF Service to return a list of this type:

```
[DataContract]
public class TestType
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and I'm using the following code:

```
int pageNumber = 0;
int pageSize = 25;

List<TestType> results = (from caseTypes in context.cch
                          select new TestType()
                          {
                              ID = caseTypes.cch_id,
                              Name = caseTypes.cch_case_ref
                          }                               
                          ).Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList<TestType>();
```

However, when i run the code I get the error:

```
The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.
```

So, if I change the code to add an orderby:

```
List<TestType> results = (from caseTypes in context.cch
                          orderby caseTypes.cch_id
                          select new TestType()
                          {
                               ID = caseTypes.cch_id,
                               Name = caseTypes.cch_case_ref
                          }                               
                          ).Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList<TestType>();
```

I then get greeted by the error message:

```
Count must have a non-negative value.
Parameter name: count
```

Am I even approaching this paging the correct way?

Comment: `.Skip((0 - 1) * 25) == -25`. How do you skip -25?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You initialized the page number as 0 so -1 is the skip parameter it's complaining about.  Initialize the page as 1.

Comment: I can't believe I've been that stupid. In my defence, I've had nothing but problems with this since I started and this will be the end of a very frustrating day. Thanks Justin!

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush lol all programmers have those days, sometimes we just need a fresh set of eyes to spot the obvious.